# How to interpret Apyori (Apriori algorithm) output for association rules longer than 2?

Tags: python, apriori

I have implemented the [Apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) algorithm to find frequent itemsets and association rules on my dataset and the [Apyori](https://pypi.org/project/apyori/) library in Python gives me these results :

```
Motif   Support  Confidence      Lift
0          [05M09T, 05M093]  0.066946    0.524590  1.628273
1  [05M091, 05M092, 05M093]  0.052301    0.581395  1.804591
```

First line is understandable, but how to deal with the second one ?
Is the association rule `{05M091} --> {05M092, 05M093}` or `{05M091, 05M092} --> {05M093}` ? Because it is not the same for the metrics computation!

Comment: This Kaggle notebook might help you: [kaggle-apriory](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ekrembayar/apriori-association-rules-grocery-store)

Comment: The example is great! Thank you. However, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post the full code? Then I can go through it and give some suggestions

Comment: Would be very nice from you. Here is the full code on the github of the project : https://github.com/Kirscher/TextMining_Parcours_de_soin/blob/main/text_mining/Apriori.ipynb